# How can I execute a shell script that exists in a longish path with a single command without first cd'ing to the directory?

Tags: shell, command-line, shell-script

In Linux I always `cd` to a longish path and then run the script:

```
cd /scratch/someDir/someOthernestedDir/
./shellscriptName.sh
```

How can I avoid achieve typing this longish path and then  executing the command with a  single step?

Some thing like the below from any path should do what I want:

```
executeMyCommand
```

P.S: I am using C-shell.

```
[subhrcho@slc04lyo bin]$ echo $0
csh
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three main ways of running your script without needing to specify the full path.

1. Add the directory containing your script to your `$PATH`. You will then be able to execute the script by name from any directory, just like any other program. If you are using `csh`, add this to your `~/.cshrc`:

   ```
   set path = ($path /scratch/someDir/someOthernestedDir/)
   ```
2. Place a link to your script in a directory that is already in your path. For example `/usr/bin`:

   ```
   ln -s /scratch/someDir/someOthernestedDir/shellscriptName.sh /usr/bin
   ```
3. Make an alias as @EightBitTony [suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85056/22222), add this line to your `~/.cshrc`:

   ```
   alias executeMyCommand '/scratch/someDir/someOthernestedDir/shellscriptName.sh'
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Command aliases.

`alias name definition`

e.g.

`alias executeMyCommand '/scratch/someDir/someOthernestedDir/shellscriptName.sh'`

[From here](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/shell/alias_csh.html).

Adding a command alias

To make a command alias a permanent part of your working environment:

1. Edit the shell startup file .cshrc and add the line defining the alias.
2. Save the changes and leave the editor.
3. Source the shell startup file to have the changes take immediate effect. For example:

   source .cshrc

Comment: Why do we need to do the last step. What does source do ?

Comment: @Geek source just tells your shell to read the `.cshrc` file again. Otherwise, your current shell will not see the new alias and it will only work once you open a new terminal.